# Solr delta import doesn't import new docs from Postgres

Tags: solr

I have a Solr instance with next DIHconfigfile

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" name="db" driver="org.postgresql.Driver" url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/db" user="user" password="password" />
    <document name="db">
        <entity name="sites" query="SELECT url, title, body, last_parse FROM sites where body is not null;"
                deltaQuery="SELECT url, title, body, last_parse FROM sites where body is not null and last_parse > '${dih.last_index_time}'"
                deltaImportQuery="SELECT url, title, body, last_parse FROM sites where body is not null and last_parse > '${dih.last_index_time}'">
            <field column="url" name="url" />
            <field column="title" name="title" />
            <field column="body" name="body" />
            <field column="last_parse" name="last_parse" />
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

It works without error, but doesn't add new data from Postgres. When I start this delta import very first time it detects about 300k new rows but update only 11 docs in index. When I try to start it again it doesn't detect anything. 
I have 3.1m rows in my Postgres and only 2.7m in Solr index. I want to Solr add all new rows from Postgres and also update docs which last_parse < than current date.

UPD - I rewrite query but it's super slow

```
<entity name="sites" pk="id"
 query="SELECT id, url, title, body, last_parse FROM sites where body is not null;"
 deltaQuery="SELECT id FROM sites WHERE body is not null and last_parse > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'"
 deltaImportQuery="SELECT id, url, title, body, last_parse FROM sites where body is not null and id = '${dataimporter.delta.id}'"
 >
```

Comment: What is `last_parse` set to for new rows? If it's NULL, it will probably not get picked up by the comparison against an actual value. Also, the `deltaQuery` is supposed to fetch the _ids_ of the rows to be imported, while the `deltaImportQuery` is supposed to fetch the row based on that id. See [DataImportHandlerDeltaQueryViaFullImport](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/DataImportHandlerDeltaQueryViaFullImport).

Comment: @MatsLindh, last_parse always set to date with format yyyy-mm-dd. "Also, the deltaQuery is supposed to fetch the ids of the rows to be imported" - therefore Do I have to change my solr scheme to include id?

Comment: No, it's just the primary key for the rows being fetched. The linked wiki page also shows how you can do everything with a single query instead. If it's a `YYYY-mm- dd` field, make sure that it actually maps properly to the format used by Solr (i.e. if it has been changed the same day, that might not be caught if Solr uses YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Comment: @MatsLindh, I rewrite my cfg but it's incredebly slow (upd body question). It founds more than 900k new docs. Can you suggest something?